# Showing null while trying to fetch email ID from Facebook in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Code for fetching user Email ID from Facebook.

```
[[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
           NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
           NSError *error) {
             if (error) {
                 //error
             }else{
                 control.name.text=user.name;
                 self.myFirstNameLabel.text = user.first_name;
                 self.myLastNameLabel.text = user.last_name;
                 self.myEmailLabel.text = ???
                 NSLog(@"name :%@",user.name);
                 NSLog(@"email is :%@",[user objectForKey:@"email"]);
             }
         }];
```

Permission for getting Email ID:

```
{ 
   NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", nil];
   [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:
    ^(FBSession *session,
   FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

     [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
 }];
```

}

but still showing null.please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you find `email` in `user` variable?

Comment: @Shadowfax :I'm gettin name,id,first name,last name,location etc..but not email

Comment: You are making call for the user in session right? and did you got the `email` in the permission window while authenticating the app?

Comment: @shadowfox: Yes in session only no am not getting..please help

Comment: Pls read this awesome doc : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while back. And I sandbagged around for a solution. But in the end it turned out the the facebook test account that I was using had no vaild email id attached to it. The gmail account through which I used to login to facebook had been deleted!